# Get full file name in PHP with file dialog

Tags: javascript, scripting, browser, file-upload

I want to get a filename to upload it with PHP to a FTP Server. But anytime I use the  I only get the filename itself, not the needed FULL path for fput...Ideas?  Everybody complaining on how to extract the filename from the path but I WANT the path :D

Comment: Please add more context. When and where do you need to get the full path of what kind of a file on which server, the local or the remote one? If possible, show some code

Comment: what have yo tried so far to accomplish this and what are your varaibles used?

Comment: I am connecting to my FTP server to upload a file. ftp_put needs the full filepath from your local HDD to upload it on the ftp. I want to make it nice and I am opening a "Open file"-dialog with <form input= file name=filename> so you can select a file. But after selecting a file, filename returns only the filename (like test.exe) and not the full path that I need for ftp_put (like C:\...\test.exe). 
How to do this?

Comment: You can't. Flash might be able to but to be honest, I've never seen before. Why would you even want this?

Comment: Great....so how to upload a file to FTP without forcing the user to write down the whole path in a textbox?

Comment: Why do you need the whole path?

Comment: For ftp_put in PHP, it needs the whole local path to the file

Comment: Why do you need the full path from the user? Can't your PHP script come up with a path? Like: /usr/Lima/files/filename.ext

Comment: Of course it can but every user has another filepath and system, so the path in Windows 7 isn't compatible with XP or OSX. I manage to upload a file but the user should upload them too..

Comment: @Lima Do you understand the difference between client side full path and server side full path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the answer still is: you can't. Not via the browser anyway.

It almost sounds as if you're writing an application that perhaps should not be a browser application, like some sort of backup application.

Comment: So, how do all those other sites manage it that I've got a "Upload" button, I select a file and then the file is uploaded? ;-) Like youtube, imageshack, etc.

Comment: @Liam They also don't have the full path, just the filename (basename).

Comment: But how how how the hell do they do this?

Comment: Do what? They only have the filename. The rest is generated by them. Of course in addition to the filename it also gets THE ACTUAL FILE, is that what you meant?

Answer (score 1):

`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];`

I think this is what you're looking for if you're automating the ftp from another server.  If you're just letting the user interact via a browser, the file will be in a temporary folder on the server uploaded to and can be handled like this -

```
$basepath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . HOME;
$directory_img = $basepath.'images/';
$fieldname = 'file';
@is_uploaded_file($_FILES[$fieldname]['tmp_name'])
or error('not an HTTP upload', $uploadForm);  

$src_name = $stock.$nbr.".jpg";
$uploadFilename = $directory_img.$src_name;
```

I've pasted here just the code that mostly pertains to your question.  Note that there may be variables that I've defined outside of these lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, the answer is you can't with PHP.  Since PHP is a server side script it has no access to the clients file directory structure.  You require a client side script to browse the client drive, like JavaScript.  You can then tell PHP the file is coming with an Ajax call or similar.